# removing mouse presence after hiding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've some code to hide the mouse after 2 seconds of no movements:

```
var justHidden = false;
var j;

function hideMouse() {
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (!justHidden) {
            justHidden = false;
            clearTimeout(j);
            $('html').css({cursor: 'default'});
            j = setTimeout(hide, 1000);
        }
    });
}

function hide() {
    $('html').css({cursor: 'none'});
    justHidden = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        justHidden = false;
    }, 500);
}
```

The code works perfectly fine, however, it doesn't cancel the mouse "presence", so if I hover on an element and it gets highlighted and stop moving for 2 seconds while still on the element, the hover highlight is still taking effect.

Is there any way I can also remove the mouse "presence" so the element will remove it's hover state?

Comment: Take a look at [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 How can I implement it?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/0Lyyopjs/ Hold your cursor still for ~5seconds to see the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just removing the cursor does exactly that, it removes the icon only, and not the functionality.

There are a few ways to do this, you can use the Pointer Lock API, but browser support is not very good.
The way to do it, is to create an element that's not visible, and lock the pointer in that element.

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.style.position = 'fixed';
elem.style.left = '-9999px';
document.body.appendChild(elem);

elem.requestPointerLock = 
    elem.requestPointerLock || 
    elem.mozRequestPointerLock || 
    elem.webkitRequestPointerLock;

elem.requestPointerLock();
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/ficesusexeke/1/edit) (hit "Run with JS")

Then there's pointer events, with somewhat better support

```
$('*').css({
    pointerEvents : 'none',
    cursor : 'none'
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruw934e/);

The last option would be to overlay a hidden element on top of the page that covers the entire window, that way all the other elements are hidden behind it. It's simple and works everywhere

```
$('<div />', {
    css: {
        position: 'fixed',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }
}).appendTo('body');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruw934e/2/)

Comment: The first one won't be convenient for the user since it will ask the user to allow pointer lock every time the cursor is stopped  for 2 seconds. The second one and the third one requires a redraw to remove current hover states style (which some browsers need that).

Comment: I tried the third one, however,  it won't remove the current element that is marked. I tried doing `$('body`).css('display','none'); $('body`).css('display','block');` to "refresh" the view but it stil doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: I just needed to do some action between the display:block and display:none for some reason. It fixed it. Thanks @Derek朕會功夫 and adeneo.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple idea, from the top of my head, didn't test it...

You could, along with hiding the cursor, add a class to the html, say `.no-cursor`.

```
function hide() {
    $('html').css({cursor: 'none'}).addClass("no-mouse");
    //...
```

And then, you subject the `:hover` rules to a condition of the html not having this class:

```
html:not(.no-mouse) div:hover {
    /*Not affecting when mouse is hidden */
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually, then, why not let this class hide the cursor?

```
html.no-cursor {
    cursor: none !important;
}
```

And just:

```
function hide() {
    $('html').addClass("no-mouse");
```